# Why is that sometimes the excel goal seek doesn't stop exactly at zero

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to do find a solution of a variable using goal seek. The problem is that the value needs to be zero, but it doesn't stop at 0.It stops at 0.002. Whereas the same goal seek stops at zero for my friend. Why is that so? Btw, there is definitely a solution. But excel doesn't provide it.

Need some guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move to the Formulas options and, in the top Calculation options, change Maximum Change to 
0.00001 (or the accuracy you require) – sometimes you may also need to change Maximum Iterations.

This should solve the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Excel SOLVER Add-In. It has more functionality, better objectives, and more User Control. It appears to better converge to the most appropriate solution for most problems. A better tool than Goal-Seek.

Answer (score -2):

It can be computing power of the computer, or it may depend on how complicated the logic is. I've had goal seeks that never get to 0 because of the large number of variables.